# Using vector to store two types of data structure

Tags: c++, class, vector, radix

I have a class called tile. Tile has the following definition:

```
class Tile
{
public:
    void readTile();
    //another public functions
private:
    unsigned char thingsCount;
    std::vector<Thing> things;
};
```

Tile has two private members: a vector of Things and a unsigned char that stores how many things there are in the tile.

Thing is a base class. Thing has the following definition:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    //public functions
private:
    ThingCategories m_category;
};
```

Thing has a private member called category. It indicates whether thing is an item or a creature, since Item class and Creature class have the following definition:

```
class Item : public Thing
{
public:
    //public functions
private:
    Position position;
    unsigned short int Id;
    unsigned char count;
};

class Creature : public Thing
{
public:
    //public functions
private:
    Position position;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string name;
    int m_speed;
};
```

The function readTile() gets all the things in a tile and stores in its private member std::vector things. Its definition is something like the following:

```
void readTile() {
    Thing _thing = readThing();
    if (_thing.getCategory() == ThingItem) {
        Item _item = readItem();
        things.push_back(_item);
    }
    else if (_thing.getCategory() == ThingCreature) {
        Creature _creature = readCreature();
        things.push_back(_creature);
    }
}
```

So it reads all the things determining the category of thing, creating an object of type Item or Creature, reading the information of that and then pulling it to the end of the vector. The problem is after this procedure when I access the std::vector things, it only has the category of the things in the tile. So it does not store the Item or Creatures object, only its category. What can I do to store these both type of data in that vector?

Thanks,

Comment: You would need to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>>` instead of `std::vector<Thing>` for example, otherwise your objects will not behave polymorphically. See the linked question for more details about that.

Comment: @CoryKramer Or kind of a `Variant`?

Comment: @mvidelgauz They are looking for polymorphic behavior, so I don't think this is an appropriate time for a `std::variant`, as that is intended for unrelated object types.

Comment: @CoryKramer You are right, I just got the impression that OP introduced base class `Thing` just for the single purpose of storing "things" in a container.

Comment: Side questions: 1: if you derived both your classes from the same base why didn't you store common members, such as `position` in the base? 2: why do you need `thingsCount`, what's wrong with `std::vector::size()'

Comment: From reading it, I understood that the Item or Creature information was not being stored, because of object slicing. To behave polymorphically in C ++, I need to implement pointers. So I used `std::vector<Thing*>` and at `readTile()` I did something like this: `Thing* itemPtr = new Item(//parameters)` and `things.push_back(itemPtr)`. While debugging, I saw that m_things are now holding a pointer but I don't know how to access its data.